# Eliminate same configuration product

Tags: python, math, cartesian-product

I have three places, and each place can take a value from the set `{1, 2, 3}`.
I am using the following python script to generate all the possible product:

```py
import itertools

options = [1, 2, 3]
for element in itertools.product(options, options, options):
  print(element)
```

Output:

```
(1, 1, 1)
(1, 1, 2)
(1, 1, 3)
(1, 2, 1)
(1, 2, 2)
(1, 2, 3)
(1, 3, 1)
(1, 3, 2)
(1, 3, 3)
(2, 1, 1)
(2, 1, 2)
(2, 1, 3)
(2, 2, 1)
(2, 2, 2)
(2, 2, 3)
(2, 3, 1)
(2, 3, 2)
(2, 3, 3)
(3, 1, 1)
(3, 1, 2)
(3, 1, 3)
(3, 2, 1)
(3, 2, 2)
(3, 2, 3)
(3, 3, 1)
(3, 3, 2)
(3, 3, 3)
```

However, in my use case I'd like to eliminate a few of these products.
For example,

1. If I have considered `(1, 1, 1)` to be an output, then we can eliminate `(2, 2, 2)` and `(3, 3, 3)`. Since both have the same configuration: **All places have the same number**.
2. If I have considered `(1, 1, 2)` to be an output, then we can eliminate `(2, 2, 3)`, `(2, 2, 1)`, `(1, 2, 1)`, `(3, 1, 3)`. Since all of them have the configuration of: **Two places should have the same number**.

Comment: You might be looking for [`itertools.combinations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations)

Comment: If I use `combinations('ABCD', 2) --> AB AC AD BC BD CD` then `AA` is missing and if I use `combinations_with_replacement('ABC', 2) --> AA AB AC BB BC CC` then both `AA` and `BB` are there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of a number, mapped to elements of a set.

In your case, we want 3 elements, so `N=3`. We then find all ways that we can sum positive integers to equal three, and allow the `i`th integer to represent the count of the `i`th element of the set present.

In this case, I'm going to use partition-generating code from [Python Algorithms and Data Structures](http://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Eeppstein/PADS/IntegerPartitions.py) by [David Eppstein](https://11011110.github.io/blog/2005/08/05/integer-partitions.html):

```py
def revlex_partitions(n):
    """
    Integer partitions of n, in reverse lexicographic order.
    The output and asymptotic runtime are the same as mckay(n),
    but the algorithm is different: it involves no division,
    and is simpler than mckay, but uses O(n) extra space for
    a recursive call stack.
    """
    if n == 0:
        yield []
    if n <= 0:
        return
    for p in revlex_partitions(n-1):
        if len(p) == 1 or (len(p) > 1 and p[-1] < p[-2]):
            p[-1] += 1
            yield p
            p[-1] -= 1
        p.append(1)
        yield p
        p.pop()
```

With this, we now just need to iterate over these partitions, and map the values:

```py
def configurations(elements, count):
    for partition in revlex_partitions(count):
        if len(partition) <= len(elements):
            yield tuple(x for x, c in zip(elements, partition) for _ in range(c))
```

Examples:

```py
>>> print(list(configurations({14, 23, 55, 78}, 4)))
[(14, 14, 14, 14), (14, 14, 14, 23), (14, 14, 23, 23), (14, 14, 23, 78), (14, 23, 78, 55)]
>>> print(list(configurations({1, 2, 3}, 4)))
[(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), (1, 1, 2, 2), (1, 1, 2, 3)]
```

Performance notes:

Asymptotically speaking, this there are an exponential number of partitions of a number, so of course the run time will be exponential. I tried some of my own modifications to the above partition algorithm (pruning elements that wouldn't meet the size requirement in advance), but was only ever able to achieve around a 4x speedup, and that was for fairly large inputs taking seconds or more.

There's also an iterative implementation of the partition function in the links above, but its also much more complex-  if performance is an issue, consider trying that one.